# Rails is using the system version of ruby instead of Chruby set default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chruby

I set my ruby default using Chruby ruby version control but when I try and rails new it is using my system version.  How do I fix this?

```
~/workspace ❯❯❯ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin14]
~/workspace ❯❯❯ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin14]
~/workspace ❯❯❯ rails new gitsee   
    Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer.

    You're running
      ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

    Please upgrade to Ruby 2.2.2 or newer to continue.
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you’ve got Rails installed in the system Ruby but not in the chruby managed 2.2.3. Since the system Ruby gem executables are in `/usr/bin/` they will be found when you are running a different version and don’t have the gem installed in that version.

To check, run `which rails` (make sure you have used `chruby` to select the recent Ruby first). You will probably see `/usr/bin/rails` as the result.

The fix is simply to install Rails in the new Ruby (again, make sure you’ve selected 2.3.1 with `chruby` first):

```
$ gem install rails
```